# Does emptiness & no-self work together?

Tags: theravada, anatman, sunyata

Emptiness seems to be very prevalent in Dhamma after Theravada.
But I have seen that it still exists in Theravada, it has just been ignored compared to other teachings.

Why is emptiness ignored so much in Theravada & can emptiness be harmonious alongside the teaching of no-self?

If my question is not clear, please inform me. :)

Metta to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the buddha says that conditioned things are empty, which means they are empty of self like he says so in https://suttacentral.net/sn35.85/en/bodhi or even https://suttacentral.net/sa273/en/choong

In fact he even says that knowing that things are empty, not self, dukkha and all that is the trigger for liberation

> ‘The first absorption is a basis for ending the defilements.’ That’s
>   what I said, but why did I say it? Take a mendicant who, quite
>   secluded from sensual pleasures, secluded from unskillful qualities,
>   enters and remains in the first absorption. They contemplate the
>   phenomena there—included in form, feeling, perception, choices, and
>   consciousness—as impermanent, as suffering, as diseased, as an
>   abscess, as a dart, as misery, as an affliction, as alien, as falling
>   apart, as empty, as not-self. They turn their mind away from those
>   things, and apply it to the deathless: ‘This is peaceful; this is
>   sublime—that is, the stilling of all activities, the letting go of all
>   attachments, the ending of craving, fading away, cessation,
>   extinguishment.’ 
>   https://suttacentral.net/an4.124/en/sujato

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Emptiness is most clearly taught in [SN 35.85](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.85/en/bodhi) and means:

> *Empty of self and of what belongs to self.*

'Emptiness' is essentially the same teaching & reality as 'anatta' ('not-self').

'Anatta' was taught in the Buddha's second sermon [SN 22.59](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.mend.html). Being the second sermon, SN 22.59 is a 'gradual teaching', where the Buddha first teaches about impermanence. The Buddha logically teaches because all of the five aggregates are impermanent, they cannot be a 'self' or cannot be controlled or possessed as 'mine'.

'Emptiness' is a later teaching, where the Buddha comprehensively says everything, be it conditioned or unconditioned, impermanent or permanent,  is empty of self.